# How to transfer bitcoins from old wallet to new wallet? Have no wallet.dat info

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet-recovery

I've been researching and trying different things for few weeks now and I hope that you guys will be able to help me out.

I'm attempting to recover my bitcoins from years ago.. but I have no wallet.dat on my backup and was wondering what's the best way to transfer them to a new wallet I've created?

Blockchain does show that I do have some BTC but I have no idea how to get it showing on the Bitcoin Core.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you were using the Bitcoin QT (aka Bitcoin Core) client, then the private keys you need are in the wallet.dat file.

If you can't get that file, and you don't have any other record of the private keys, I'm sorry to say your funds are lost.

If you had used the Electrum wallet instead, you could recover your keys using the 12 word "seed", if you had that.

There were other wallets in use too; if you think you used something else as a wallet, let us know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm able to log into Blockchain without any issues and its showing me a balance.. I do have a 'Wallet Recovery Mnemonic' if I can do anything with that?

Comment: I think I've just figured out how to get the private key for it but still have no idea how to go about transferring without it having any implications?

Comment: @TomB If you import your private key to a wallet you control (ie not a 3rd part web based one) such as Bitcoin Core or Electrum, then you are still able to get your Bitcoin Cash and Bitcoin Gold from those forks if you so choose. You may like to read more on how to do it safely if you do that though. How to import a private key to a particular wallet is a question that should be asked separately, if you need help with that.

Comment: @TomB if you have the recover mnemonic then you should be fine. You can use any wallet that follows BIP 32 for deterministically regenerating your private keys based on your BIP 39 mnemonic. For example: Bread Wallet. Most wallets that follow those standards have a "Recover Wallet" feature. If you do that, you will have access to your BTC and be able to spend them. You don't need to send them anywhere to have access to them.